# Strategy for generating statistics with user data

Tags: database, statistics

I need a general piece of advice, but for the record i use jpa.

I need to generate usage data statistics, eg breakdown of user purchases per product, etc... I see three possible strategies, 1) generate on the fly stats each time the stats are being viewed, 2) create a specific table for stats that i would update each time there is a change 3) do offline processing at regular time intervals

All have issues and advanages, eg cost vs not up to date data, and i was wondering if anyone with experience in this field could provide some advice. I am aware the question s pretty broad, i can refine my use case if needed.

Comment: Before I try to answer I'd ask, what does the business want as far as responsiveness? The second question is how much data do you have? Are we talking millions of records, thousands?

Comment: Ha, yes indeed, excellent question ;-) how much data - wrt the order/customer data I mentioned, this is around several 10k users, each with around 100 orders, that could include 10 products each. I might need to produce stats at each level (product types vs user or users vs orders, etc...). Responsiveness, I must admit I am not too sure. I guess completely up to date (given the amount of data we have), which does indeed precludes 3) as an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a lot of reporting and the first question I always want to know is if the stakeholder needs the data in real time or not. This definitely shifts how you think and how you'll design a reporting system.

Based on the size of your data, I think it's possible to do real time reporting. If you had data in the millions, then maybe you'd need to do some pre-processing or data warehousing (your options 2/3).

Some general recommendations:

1. If you want to do real time reporting, think about making a copy of the database so you aren't running reports against production data. Some reports can use queries that are heavy, so it's worth looking into replicating production data to some other server where you can run reports.
2. Use intermediate structures a lot for reports. Write views, stored procedures, etc. so every report isn't just some huge complex query.
3. If the reports start to get too complex for doing at the database level, make sure you move the report logic into the application layer. I've been bitten by this many times. I start writing a report with queries purely from the database and eventually it gets too complex and I have to jump through hoops to make it work.
4. Shoot for real time and then go to stale data if necessary. Databases are capable of doing a lot more than you'd think. Quite often you can make changes to your database structures that will give you a big yield in performance.

Comment: Thanks for some great recommendations. I will try to follow them. If it locks, I will move to plan B as you suggested.